# Ubuntu 16.04 with 4.13 kernel freezes on swap

Tags: 16.04, kernel, freeze, swap

After ungrading to 4.13 kernel I got problem on my ThinkPad S540 with 16Gb RAM and SSD + HDD. Now when reaching top of RAM usage system completely freezes. Sometimes mouse pointer may slowly move. Switching to console and back does not help. Unable to run xkill or reboot from command line (console login never completes). The only way to reboot os POWER button.

I have two swap files: one on SSD and another on HDD. Switching from one swap to another (from SSD to HDD) did not help. System still hangs on swapping.

The only thing helped is rolling back to kernel 4.10.0-42.

Is there any way to diagnose and resolve this issue?

Comment: Not a solution, but if you have enough ram (atleast 4gigs), you can disable hdd swap, and install zram instead.

Comment: Thank you. This is really not a solution, because I have 16GB RAM and I need it all when running Gradle for example. Swapping immediately freezes whole OS :(

Comment: I suggested zswap because it will delay the swapping on hdd, which makes you suffer from freezing. Instead it will compress and store in a part of the memory. Which is way more faster than swapping directly to hdd. If the memory is completely full, then it will move those to hdd

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. The reason in my case was having both out of swap space and out of memory. I created a simple bash script to automatically increase/decrease swap space continuously if having too less/too much memory available. It keeps memory performance optimal by disabling swap space when enough free memory available.

See https://github.com/make/autoswap